# Why Use Multi-Container Endpoints instead of Multi-Model Endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

In the SageMaker documentation, both [Multi-Model Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/multi-model-endpoints.html) and [Multi-Container Endpoints with Direct Invocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/multi-container-direct.html) are described as very similar methods to host multiple models on a single endpoint. The given use cases appear identical except that **Multi-Model Endpoints** include many more advanced features.

For example, **Multi-Model Endpoints** can host *n* number of models and support features such as resource sharing and model caching while **Multi-Container Endpoints with Direct Invocation** are limited to hosting only 5 models and lack model caching.

When does it make sense to use **Multi-Container Endpoints with Direct Invocation** instead of **Multi-Model Endpoints**?

[image: Multi-Model Endpoint]
[image: Multi-Container Endpoint with Direct Invocation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serve multiple models from the same framework using the same endpoint then you can use multi-model endpoints. Due to using the same framework (e.g. only sklearn models), multi-model endpoints make it to the endpoint when they are called. You can have thousands of those models under one endpoint. Multi-container endpoints on the other hand allow serving models from multiple frameworks, e.g. one TensorFlow, one XGBoost and so on, with direct invocation again. However in this case there's [limit of 5 different models](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/multi-container-direct.html) on a single endpoint.

So depending on the problem you are working, if you need to use multiple frameworks on a single endpoint then you will need to use multi-container endpoint with direct invocation. Otherwise you can use the multi-model endpoint.

[Reference](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-thousands-of-models-on-sagemaker-real-time-endpoints-with-automatic-retraining-pipelines-4eef7521d5a3)

Comment: Can you use both? I imagine having a Multi-Container endpoint with two containers (TensorFlow and Sklearn) set up in a Multi-Model way, so that I call an endpoint and tell it "hit TensorFlow container with model XYZ".